# Horizontal menu is displayed vertically in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, menu

Ok so I know there are a few similar questions on here but I can't seem to fix my problem with the solutions I read. I'm making a new website and the menu is displayed horizontally in Chrome and Firefox but it is displayed vertically in older versions of Internet Explorer or in Internet Explorer's compatibility mode. Here are the screenshots to compare:

Chrome: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRRIz.jpg

Internet Explorer (compatibility mode): https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2sY2.jpg

Not only the menu looks broken, but a few things look misplaced. Fixing the menu would be a good place to start.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div id="menu">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Tires
                <ul>
                    <li>Utility
                        <ul>
                            <li>Gripper</li>
                            <li>Radical</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>Sport
                        <ul>
                            <li>Race-X</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Contact
                <ul>
                    <li>About us</li>
                    <li>Contact us</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Dealers
                <ul>
                    <li>Locate a dealer</li>
                    <li>Become a dealer</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Downloads</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS code:

```
#menu {
    height: 40px;
    width: 960px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    color: #FFF;
    float: left;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -2px #888;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -2px #888;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -2px #888;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    background: #333;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

nav ul {
    background: #333;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #000 0%, #4B4B4B 100%);  
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #000 0%, #4B4B4B 100%); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #000 0%, #4B4B4B 100%); 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}

nav ul:after {
    content: ""; 
    clear: both; 
    display: block;
}

nav ul li {
    width: 20%;
    background: #333;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #000;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #000;
    float: left;
}

nav ul li:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px #000;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px #000;
}

nav ul li.active {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px #000;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px #000;
}

nav ul li a {
    display: block; 
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul ul {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
    width: 20%;
    background: #333;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    top: 100%;
}

nav ul ul li {
    width: 100%;
    float: none; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #494949;
    position: relative;
}

nav ul ul li:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 #868686;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 #868686;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 #868686;
    background: #868686;
    color: #FFF;
}

nav ul ul li a {
    line-height: 35px;
    height: 35px;
}   

nav ul ul li a:hover {
    background: #868686;
}

nav ul ul ul {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute; 
    left: 100%; 
    top:0;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This question is poorly titled and worded. The CSS is not loading (correctly) in IE. This is a commmon error. Give me a few minutes or another user may pick it up - alternatively, consider putting up a new question along the lines of 'CSS not loading in IE'

Comment: Older IE's don't support `nav` tag...

Comment: +1 @Teemu I didn't pick that up right away. So if OP is using IE9 then it could be something else?

Comment: @redditor We don't know, OP didn't tell the exact versions, but this should work in IE9.

Comment: I'm using IE9 in compatibility mode. When not in compatibility mode it works fine. When I try loading up the website on older computers with IE the menu also appears vertically.

Comment: What comes to the non-working menu, the `:hover` can't change all properties of an element in older IEs. You can see a warning about this in the console. If you want to get your menu to work in these browsers, you need to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like IE is not recognising the *nav* element. IE in Compatibility mode interprets the markup as follows:

```
<div id="menu">
    <nav />
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            ...
        </ul>
</div>
```

Notice how the *nav* element self-closes. This means that none of your CSS rules match the markup. (You can see this for yourself by using the developer tools bundled with later versions of IE - press F12)

I suggest changing your CSS rules by replacing references to *nav* with *#menu*, and this should work across a range of IE versions.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I just did this and it looks great except that the menu won't drop down. When I drag my mouse over the menu it does nothing.

Comment: See feitla's answer below: You'll need to add some javascript to get the dynamic drop down behaviour to work for IE versions less than 9.

Answer (score 1):

To add on to the correct answer above...

If you plan on using HTML5 then include shim...

```
<!-- HTML5 shim -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```